# PC powers on but doesn't boot

Tags: boot, motherboard, desktop-computer

My pc powers on and fans start running when i press the power button but monitor shows nothing and no boot sound from pc. I removed the memory modules, gpu, hdd but the pc still doesn't boot or doesn't give any noise. There is no other card plugged into the motherboard.

There was recent upgrade, system change etc. It was working fine until now.

What may be the problem?

**UPDATE:** It turns out that the problem is caused by the motherboard. The technician said the capacitors broke down. I replaced the motherboard and now it runs fine.

Comment: I can't comment - reputation - so I put this in an answer: I have the same problem when my graphic card have die. But in your case may be something related to bios. Tell us about OS and upgrade, was a firmware, a graphic driver?

Comment: No, no update or sth, nothing, i even disconnected the hdd, just to hear a error noise from motherboard but nothing happens.

Comment: Source(ac/dc)? The fan starts?

Comment: yes fans start, standart atx psu

Comment: When you say "the monitor show nothing", does it remain in sleep mode, or does it wake up only to display a black screen ?

Comment: it is an lcd monitor, it doesn't detect any signal from vga input.

Comment: A shot in the dark: What's the brand of your PC? A pre-build one like a Dell? Or a self-manufactured. If so, do you know the board+PSU brand?

Comment: It is pre-built, a local brand, motherboard's brand is MSI, i checked the psu with another psu, it seems psu is not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here with 2 machines.

No standard reason. Can be a lot of things.

Basically take the machine apart and rebuild it component by component - first with as little externals as possible to the mobo (you need minimal ram, cooling etc., but not necessary graphics card, when on board exists, and no hard disc).

THe problem may be a broken motherboard or CPU or anything - basicalyl machines DO fail. Capacitator failure on the mother board being an anectodal high chance reason. But then it may also be the power supply.

Really, best take it to a shop - unless you have enough various parts to try things out. A technician will just be able to play around with it for 10 minutes with cheap known working replacement parts.

Comment: I removed the rams, gpu, hdd still no boot. The only things left are cpu, psu and motherboard.

Comment: Yeah. And that is where having another computer ready comes in handy. At leat the PSU is a fast check with a replacement - cpu and mobo are harder. I don't look forward to my IT guy checking our 2 machines. THat said, thank heavne, they are old.